# How do I display a image button in front of an image in Android?

Tags: java, android

I am really new to programming and I've got a problem I've been making a game and all the the borders and backgrounds are images and I've been trying to find a away to display an image button so I can do a settings menu but I don't know what to do next please help. this is how I've done my button

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ImageButton myButton = new ImageButton(this);
        myButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.settings);
        myButton.setId(1);
        RelativeLayout myLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams buttonParams =
                new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        myLayout.addView(myButton, buttonParams);
        setContentView(myLayout);

        myButton.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        onButtonClick(v);
                    }
                });


    }

    public void onButtonClick(View v) {
        //do something when button is clicked.

        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, v);
        MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.contextitems, popup.getMenu());
        popup.show();

    }
```

and this is how I'm displaying the images

```
 @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {


        final float scaleFactorX = getWidth() / (WIDTH * 1.f);
        final float scaleFactorY = getHeight() / (HEIGHT * 1.f);

        if (canvas != null) {


            final int savedState = canvas.save();
            canvas.scale(scaleFactorX, scaleFactorY);

            bg.draw(canvas);
            if (!dissapear) {
                player.draw(canvas);
            }
            //draw smokepuffs
            for (Smokepuff sp : smoke) {
                sp.draw(canvas);
            }
            //draw missiles
            for (Missile m : missiles) {
                m.draw(canvas);
            }


            //draw topborder
            for (TopBorder tb : topborder) {
                tb.draw(canvas);
            }

            //draw botborder
            for (BotBorder bb : botborder) {
                bb.draw(canvas);
            }
            //draw explosion
            if (started) {
                explosion.draw(canvas);
            }


            drawText(canvas);
            canvas.restoreToCount(savedState);

        }


    }
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are programmatically generating the ImageButton? Why can't you add it via the XML?

Comment: I was following an tutorial and that's the way he had done it he didn't really say why though

Comment: Can you add the `activity_main` layout XML to your question?

Comment: the main programming and is all done in a separate class to the  main activity and the activite_main layout XML doesn't do anything

Comment: On the contrary it does do something at the line `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`. If you want something to "overlay" your main content view, I think we'll need to see it.

Comment: that was not ment to be there

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Layer List (drawable).

```
<bitmap 
      android:src="@drawable/your_photo"
      android:gravity="center" />
```

Comment: Did you tried this `yourButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.new_image);`